# Code Signing 'ios 10.0' - without signing team

Tags: code-signing, ios10, xcode8

[image]

I know there's been many similar posts for this - but I didn't quiet find what I needed, please help me on this.

I've only access "provisional profile + code signing certificate" (provided by different department) to create release version. So I don't really have access to "team" ids.

Now, I would like to follow the same / similar method without having to login team option for Xcode 8 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to be a part of any development team.

From https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

> The new automatically managed code signing generates all the assets
>   you need to properly sign, provision, and run your apps on a connected
>   Apple device. Simply choose your team and Xcode does the rest. You
>   also have the option of hand-picking your provisioning profiles and
>   setting up the signing process for each build configuration.

All you have to do - is to login with your apple development account, then uncheck "Automatically manage signing" in **Target > General** settings, and manually select provisioning profile as you always did.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response!
but can this be done without having to sign into development account as well? Previously this wasn't really required.

Comment: You don't have to buy a membership from apple, simply login with your Apple ID onto https://developer.apple.com and agree with developer's terms and conditions.

Comment: hello @andrii , i did get what you suggested & that might be the best solution.

But my question isn't really that - **i'm looking for the workaround** .i.e. **not having to login atall** (as was possible before) : is that still possible in some ways ?